# C# how to get the count on a pop message box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, counter, messagebox

I am making a bulk mail sender which will take mail addresses from DB. All is okay, test mails are sending but the success message is showing only after all the mails are sent. I want a message box or a progress box to count the mails that are passing. Help me to add a message pomp to count the mails have been sending. Here the Code I am using for sending mails, please write me the code for the message box to show the count -

```
private void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
string subject = txtSubject.Text;
string message = txtMessage.Text;            
if (!txtFile.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
{
    if (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtFile.Text).Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtFile.Text))
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

var con = "Data Source=Ashiq-pc;Initial Catalog=OfferMails;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
List<EmailModel> emailList = new List<EmailModel>();
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
{
    string oString = "Select * from tbl_MailAdd where Flag=@Flag";
    SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
    oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", true);     
    myConnection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (oReader.Read())
        {
            EmailModel emailModel = new EmailModel();
            emailModel.ID = Convert.ToInt16(oReader["ID"]);
            emailModel.EmailAdd = oReader["EmailAdd"].ToString();
            emailModel.Flag = Convert.ToBoolean(oReader["Flag"]);
            emailList.Add(emailModel);                 
        }

        myConnection.Close();
    }               
}

//return matchingPerson;
foreach (EmailModel email in emailList)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 100000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("my mail", "my pass");
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(email.EmailAdd);
        msg.From = new MailAddress("my from name");
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = message;
        if (!txtFile.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
        {
            if (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtFile.Text).Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtFile.Text))
                {
                    //Add file in ListBox.
                    listAttch.Items.Add(file);
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + file, "Message");
                    Attachment data = new Attachment(file);
                    msg.Attachments.Add(data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(“No files Found at location : {0}”, textBox1.Text));
            }
        }
        //Attachment data = new Attachment(textBox_Attachment.Text);
        //msg.Attachments.Add(data);
        client.Send(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

//for (int i = 0; i < emailList.Count; i++)
//{
//    MessageBox.Show("i++");
//}

MessageBox.Show("Successfully Sent Message.");
```

}

Comment: Is the ASP.NET tag appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

First, let me just say that asking for someone to write this code for you is a bit frowned upon here. But I know what you're asking so I'm willing to help out a bit.

Firstly, a message box by itself isn't going to work for this, because a message box ends up stopping the thread where it is until a the `DialogResult` event is handled. So, for that being said, you will probably want to build another form (I am assuming that you're doing this with Windows Forms here.) to do the progress for you. If you want it to be a counter, then you could do it using a label that is changing its text as each mail is sent.

So, with that being said, however, if you're doing this with a Windows Form, the issue you will run into is the form will never update until after your
`foreach` loop finishes. This is because of the way that C# handles thread usage.

For what you want to accomplish, you'll need to utilize the `BackgroundWorker.` This allows you to run cumbersome operations asynchronously.

Here is an example that you could use to get your system working:

```
//used to be a counter for your progress
int i_counter = 0;

//create  a background worker instance
public BackgroundWorker bg_worker = new BackgroundWorker();



public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //set this to true if you want to have an event where you can cancel the background task
    bg_worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    //this is needed to actually show your progress, allows the background worker to report it is working
    bg_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    //assigns the "DoWork" and "ProgressChanged" Handlers to the background worker.
    bg_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_worker_DoWork);
    bg_worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bg_worker_ProgressChanged);
}

//Mail method
public void MailerMethod()
{
    //all of the things you want to happen for your mailing methods

    foreach(//your loop stuff in here)
    {
        //THIS NEEDS TO HAPPEN TO CAUSE THE COUNTER TO UPDATE
        bg_worker.ReportProgress(i_counter);
    }

}



//the stuff that you want done in the background
//fires when "RunAsync" is called by BackgroundWorker object.
private void bg_worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    //IN HERE IS WHERE YOU WANT YOUR EMAIL STUFF TO HAPPEN
    bg_worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    MailerMethod();//or just all of your mailing code, it looks nicer like this though

}

//fires when worker reports the progress has changed
//caused by "ReportProgress" method
private void bg_worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lb_counter.Text = Convert.ToString(i_counter);
}

  //this is what will happen when the worker is done.
  //you can have it do a alot of things, such as write a report, show a window, etc.
private void bg_worker_RunWorkComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("DONE!", "DING DING!");
    Application.Exit();

}


//button click event to start this shindig
private void bt_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //makes sure the background worker isn't already trying to run
    if (!bg_worker.IsBusy)
    {
        //calls the DoWork event
        bg_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        bt_start.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

May I direct you [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) for the official MDSN documentation.
And [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) for a basic tutorial on how to set up a `BackgroundWorker`.

Hope this helps, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Through you reference I have learned a lot. I have added one more button called stop. Everything is fine, no error occurred. But the label is not showing any progress and the the button Stop is not responding while the app is running.. I used your code and the references you gave. Let's see how I get my solution.

Comment: Update your question with your current code and explain more where some of the issues are. More help might come from that if you're truly stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Progress bar with its Position property set to zero, Max property set to the number of emails you are sending and the Step property set to 1, unless you want to step every 10 or so emails then you would use % 10 in your loop to increase the progress. In your loop simply increase the position of the ProgresBar or call Step().

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't the progress bar just freeze because the UI would execute the foreach loop entirely before updating the UI? I could be totally off but that was my assumption.

Comment: Not necessary. If ashiq wants to go the extra mile and this is a production application then your suggestion is preferable. However, having a progress bar in that for each loop will work as it will continue to receive paint request from the main application. It just will not be as performant as spawning a thread to have its own draw messages.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.